# MockMvc remains null

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, junit5

I'd like to perform an integration test. My current approach:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = Application.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath: application-test.yml")
public class UserControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @DisplayName(" sda")
    public void test1(){

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

I placed @AutoConfigureMockMvc, but the MockMvc object remains null

Comment: Can you add the error message you get when running the test?

Comment: @Sebastian NPE is just thrown

Comment: I thought there might be some more information about the Spring context that is being intialized.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't really understand what was the purpose of such a test, let me explain...

Usually MockMvc is used to test the web layer of the application.

This means that under the hood spring runs "something" that can mimic the requests sent to controllers so that you could check that the annotations are placed correctly, the conversion of objects is done in a proper way, etc. In other words its like testing the controller, but it has nothing to do with services, DAOs, etc. Usually the references to the services from controller can be annotated with `@MockBean` so that spring will create a stub for services and you'll be able to describe the interactions. Other things like DAOs should never be referenced from controllers anyway (don't them ? ;) ) but in general the same pattern of mocking out these dependencies is applicable here.

Technically its done as follows:
The web mvc test (when annotated properly) doesn't load the whole application context but   a "slice" of it - only beans relevant for the web layer.

Now `@SpringBootTest` annotation does something different. Its designed especially for spring boot application and allows to mimic the whole spring application load. Out of my head (maybe other colleagues will enrich this list), it "adds up" to the regular application context starting:

- Properties configuration management
- Starters (auto-configuration modules)
- Package structure specific scanning for Beans and configurations

Bottom line, it allows starting Spring Boot Test out of some specific configuration or the whole application, **it has nothing to do with a web layer only**.

So, what I don't understand is what exactly is expected to be tested here.
If your goal is testing a web layer, then you don't have to use Spring Boot annotation (in addition to what I've already explained, spring boot test takes much more time to load)

If your goal is testing the microservice at a whole or sometimes a specific slice of it, then you can use @SpringBootTest` annotation.

Comment: It might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276555/when-to-use-runwith-and-when-extendwith

Comment: It's a monolith. The goal is to test REST enpoints methods through all layers

Comment: If you want to test the flow, don't use MockMvc... Again, MockMvc is used to test only RestControllers but it doesn't load the service layer at all.

Comment: Not sure, what should be used instead?

Comment: Only SpringBootTest... It will run the whole app (regardless whether is a monolith or microservice). MockMvc = Mock Server with access to controllers and no access to Business Logic Layer. SpringBootTest = whole application. You can inject controllers  into the test (Autowire) and call them as if they're regular java classes. or you can even start a whole web server and call through real http or something.

Comment: I need mockMvc to perform rest methods

Comment: No you don't :) Again, MockMvc is not an http client. Its a test tool given by spring developers to test the controller.

Comment: Isn't a restcontroller a type of controller? for example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_rest_controller_unit_test.htm how would you comment this?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed. you can use mock mvc to test controller/rest-controller but only controllers. When you use mock mvc it doesn't load the service beans at all, only controller beans.

Comment: It it helps you can see that it resembles https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-data-jpa-test/ with the difference that this one used to load "slice" that is relevant to database (JPA, spring data, etc) and web mvc loads the "slice" of web. If you need more clarifications - feel free to move this discussion to chat

Comment: but I should be able to autowire controller ->service ->repository, but it doesn't work. it remains null too, the appropriate bean is found in compile time as IDE shows though

Comment: MockMvc nad SpringBootTest play role at runtime. With mock mvc you're not expected to get Services and Repositories as I've originally explained... Only a slice of controller.

Comment: The thing is I've done it before in microservice application with the same configuration like that and it worked. By the way I know what's repository, service, controller unit testing ;)

Comment: Maybe the configurations are different in this spring boot application. I didn't mean unit testing at all, both spring-boot-test and mock-mvc are integration testing tools...

Comment: yes, I want to do an inegration test. Give me then please proper standard class schema. I thought @ AutoConfigureMockMvc  + @ MockMvc and @ Autowiring Controller should be enough

Comment: Nah, the configuration is the same, the thing is i didn;t exlude junit from spring boot test starter dependency, becuse there was other, older tests in junit4 in project and the problem arrived because of I annotated  by accident a test method with @ Test annotation from junit instead of jupiter.. I came up with that becuase it worked with @RunWith but not @ ExtendWith from junit 5

Answer (score 0):

If you annotate your test with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` your mockMvc will not be null.

Comment: well, I don't use jUnit4

Comment: actually failedToLoadApplicationContext when switched to @RunWith

Comment: On Junit 5 you indeed need to use @ExtendWith, thats not an issue :)

Comment: Also, on my pc I tried to remove @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath: application-test.yml") and (classes = Application.class) and my mockMvc is not null.(I had to remove those 2 things since you haven't shown those 2 things). Maybe there is where problem lies.

Comment: yes, but it works only with @RunWith *junit4, not with junit5  @ ExtendWith for some reason

Comment: When you added comment about junit5 I tried with @ExtendWith. I took your example, copy paste and just removed those 2 things. So, for some reason on my machine this is working fine with junit5.

Comment: see my comment to previous answer