# Migrating from JUnit4 to JUnit5: Runner

Tags: java, junit4, junit5, runner

I have a class written that extends Runner (org.junit.runner.Runner), which is a part of the `junit-4.13.2.jar`. I am trying to migrate to `JUnit 5` without using the `JUnit Vintage` engine. Is there a counterpart for the same class in `JUnit 5`, i.e., is there a way to migrate completely to `JUnit 5`?

Comment: JUnit 5 uses extensions for this.

Comment: In `JUnit 5` we use `@ExtendWith`. Take a look here for more details: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-runwith

Comment: This question explains it nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276555/when-to-use-runwith-and-when-extendwith

Comment: It really depends on the exact runners you’re using. Some have an equivalent extension, some require another test-engine, for others you’ll have to do the migration to a JUnit5 extension yourself. In very rare cases, a 1-1 migration might not be possible at all. So which runners are you talking about?

Comment: @M.Deinum, what extensions?

Comment: @johanneslink, I am talking about the abstract class (public abstract class Runner implements Describable), from the package org.junit.runner

Comment: As said, there’s no generic solution for the abstract Runner. There are only solutions for concrete usages.

Comment: The one that are used with `@ExtendWith` which also need a specific interface to implement. You probably need to rewrite your runner for that, or if it is a 3rd party runner look for the JUnit5 alternative, if there isn't keep using JUnit4 (through the vintage runner) or rewrite it yourself.